# Redirect parent not childs htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento

In my magento module there is an extension.
Some urls like

1. http://www.domain.com/abc/p#abcs.html
2. http://www.domain.com/abc/p#xyz.html

etc

But when browsing http://www.domain.com/abc/p -> lead to blank page

I do not need http://www.domain.com/abc/p url

Is anybody help me
I want to redirect the url http://www.domain.com/abc/p to 404 page
without affecting its childs

ie 
 1. http://www.domain.com/abc/p#abcs.html
 2. http://www.domain.com/abc/p#xyz.html
Points to its current position and

http://www.domain.com/abc/p to 404
Any help apperciated

Comment: So `http://www.domain.com/abc/p#abcs.html` shows proper content but `http://www.domain.com/abc/p` shows blank page?

Comment: yes the extesion has content in http://www.domain.com/abc/p#abcs.html
But when browsing http://www.domain.com/abc/p shows blank poage
i wnt to redirect http://www.domain.com/abc/p to 404
not its childs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment it seems `http://www.domain.com/abc/p#abcs.html` shows proper content but `http://www.domain.com/abc/p` shows blank page.

In that case you can't do that via `.htaccess` because on server side URL will always be: `http://www.domain.com/abc/p`.

You need to put some custom Javascript in your page and redirect to some non-existant page (resulting in 404) by checking `location.href` using your Javascript.